# Is there an easy way to insert a term into Elasticsearch QueryDSL using Java?

Tags: java, json, elasticsearch

I am trying to take JSON from an external source and add one condition to it before running it as a query.  I know I can do this:

```
var qb = QueryBuilders.wrapperQuery(json);
var searchSourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder();
searchSourceBuilder.query(qb);
```

... but then I want to add must match (term:value) to this DSL

Is there a good way to do this in Java?

Answer (score 1):

To be straight and simple:

```
    BoolQueryBuilder boolQueryBuilder = QueryBuilders.boolQuery();
    QueryBuilder qb = QueryBuilders.wrapperQuery("");
    boolQueryBuilder.must(qb).must(QueryBuilders.termQuery("",""));
    SearchSourceBuilder searchSourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder();
    searchSourceBuilder.query(boolQueryBuilder);
```

Comment: The issue I was having got pushed aside by other stuff so I didnt check if this works, but I saved your answer for later reference.  thank you!